# Blob and JSON: How to encode and decode

Tags: json, dart, blob

Dart's JSON.encode and JSON.decode doesn't work with BLOB SQL type. I was searching for a solution and found a lot of explanations on why it doesn't work out of the box (or natively).

So I would like to know how can I encode and decode BLOB data with JSON efficiently.

EDIT 1: Adding an example.

I have a TEXT type field called "some_text" on a MySQL database. Here follows its content:
"This is some_text field content".

When SQLJocky returns some_text, it is stored in Dart on a var as "Blob". A simple "returnVar.runtimeType" confirms it.

So now I need to "convert" this Blob text to a normal String, as JSON.encode/decode doesn't work with the first.

Comment: JSON does not have a data type for "pure binary" data.  If you want to put arbitrary blob data into a JSON stream you need to convert it using Base64 or some such.

Comment: `import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';`
`CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(bytes);`, `CryptoUtils.base64StringToBytes(input);`
If you need more support you should add the exact Dart datatype of your data `BLOB SQL type` is not very specific.

Comment: Günter, the field is set as TEXT in the MySQL database. It comes out of sqljocky as Blob (.runTimeType says it).

Comment: So how does your data look like?

Comment: @Robert, this time I'm working with a simple text on that field (actually it contains HTML markups like <p>, <ul>, etc). But I'm trying to understand how BLOB works in order to be able to save files with it in the future (like image files).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, I've added some information on the question. I think that will help.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, not tested though

```dart
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

var base64String = CryptoUtils.bytesToBase64(yourBlob.toBytes());
```

the other direction

```dart
var blob = new Blob.fromBytes(CryptoUtils.base64StringToBytes(base64String));
```

Comment: Günter, I tested it and the String that was set to the first var (base64String) was all "scrambled"/encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather old but maybe this can still be useful to someone.

I also needed to extract string from a field returned as Blob by **sqljocky** and I found from the [source code](https://github.com/dart-db/sqljocky5/blob/f4d4f8bd263b2398aa4d1654cc187499d711f3d8/lib/src/blob.dart) that Blob has two methods to extract data '*toString()*' and '*toBytes()*'. So in order to encode the sqljocky row containing Blob data and extracting it as string, the code will look like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:sqljocky5/sqljocky.dart';
...
var rowText = json.encode(row, toEncodable: (dynamic item) {
    if (item is Blob) {
        return item.toString();
    }
    return item;
});
```